# How to pass Azure blob file path url in ChoParquetReader method?

Tags: c#, blob, parquet, choetl

As per the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5270332/Cinchoo-ETL-Parquet-Reader?msg=5899324#xx5899324xx), i'm able to pass parquet file from my local folder and able to convert the data into json format. Below is sample code

```
MemoryStream jsonMs = new MemoryStream();
using (var r = new ChoParquetReader(FILE_NAME))
                {
                    using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(jsonMs))
                        w.Write(r);
                }
```

Could any one help me out on how to pass file path which is present in Azure blob?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As `ChoParquetReader` accepts any memorystream as input, just open Azure blob for read and pass it to reader.

for your reference, this sample may helps

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionString");
var desContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
var desBlob= desContainer.GetBlockBlobClient("PARQUET file");

using (var outStream = await desBlob.OpenReadAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false))
using (ChoParquetReader parser = new ChoParquetReader(outStream))
{
}
```

PS: code is not tested.